# ffmpeg export multichannel audio Stereo won't play

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, export

I am trying to export all audio channels from a multichannel quicktime file with ffmpeg which has the following audio configuration, but am unsure if the command below is correct. All the files look and play correct in Quicktime player except the L+R_Total.wav which refuses to play in Quicktime player or Final Cut but plays fine in VLC, so i'm sure my ffmpeg command is not correct for the stereo on Track 7. The Stereo file is about 1.8GB in size. Here is my track layout in the Quicktime file:

```
Track 1 - mono
Track 2 - mono
Track 3 - mono
Track 4 - mono
Track 5 - mono
Track 6 - mono
Track 7 - stereo
```

I am using:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/python/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /Users/me/Desktop/test.mov -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:1 -y Left.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:2 Right.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:3 Center.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:4 LFE.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:5 Left_Surround.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:6 Right_Surround.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:7 Left+Right_Total.wav
```

Here is the printout from the terminal:

```
    MacBook-Pro:~ me$ /Users/me/Desktop/python/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /Users/me/Desktop/test.mov -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:1 -y Left.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:2 Right.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:3 Center.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:4 LFE.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:5 Left_Surround.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:6 Right_Surround.wav -acodec pcm_s24le -map 0:7 Left+Right_Total.wav
ffmpeg version 2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 25 2014 15:00:55 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/me/Desktop/test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
  Duration: 00:01:03.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 153967 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 144704 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:8(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:26:04
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Output #0, wav, to 'Left.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #1, wav, to 'Right.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #2, wav, to 'Center.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #2:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, mono, s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #3, wav, to 'LFE.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #3:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #4, wav, to 'Left_Surround.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #4:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #5, wav, to 'Right_Surround.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #5:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32, 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Output #6, wav, to 'Left+Right_Total.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    ISFT            : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #6:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:2 -> #1:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:3 -> #2:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:4 -> #3:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:5 -> #4:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:6 -> #5:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:7 -> #6:0 (pcm_s24le -> pcm_s24le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    8927kB time=00:01:03.48 bitrate=1152.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:71415kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -87.499863%
```

Comment: Have you read this? http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1042

Comment: Unfortunately not. I want to export individual wav files from my quicktime mov, 6 mono wavs and 1 stereo wav.

Comment: Ah ok see my answer then.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.
Your question is offtopic for [so]. It does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question can be voted/flagged for migration to [su].

Comment: sorry about the wrong forum, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `ffmpeg -i Feature.mov -map 0:7 -c copy Left_Total.wav` and see if this works?

We need to make sure the data inside the stereo stream can be used by ffmpeg. Quicktime files can contain proprietary container/codec info that ffmpeg cannot read.

Comment: This gives me an error: Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy), should it be 0:7. Changing it to 0:7 gives me a file, but it wont play. This was the output, Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, downmix, 2304 kb/s (default)

Comment: Yeah sorry correct track is  0:7 I got confused in the track number. Can you play this stereo track in the original container mov? What are you using to play it back? Can you try `ffmpeg -i Feature.mov -map 0:7 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k output.mp3`

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: So running ffmpeg -i Feature.mov -map 0:7 -c copy Left_Total.wav produces a file which won't play in quicktime player or Final cut, but will play in VLC, so there is something not right with how ffmpeg if creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the issue. In the Quicktime file all Audio tracks are named and flagged as Left, Right, Center, LFE, Left Surround, Right Surround, Left Total, Right Total. ffmpeg does not like the fact that Track 7 is flagged as Left Total Right Total, when this is the case it produces a file which wont play. If I re-flag Track 7 to just Left and Right in Quicktime Pro and save the file then ffmpeg runs and the file plays fine. Is there anyway around this, I don't want to manually re-flag track 7 each time before running the ffmpeg script.

With the Quicktime file Track 7 flagged as Left Total Right Total I get the below from ffmpeg:

```
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
```

With the Quicktime file Track 7 flagged as Left Right I get the below from ffmpeg:

```
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2014-03-06 11:25:34
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
```

UPDATE:
More information gathered. I decided to roll back ffmpeg version by version to see if it made any difference.
The issue id with ffmpeg correctly carrying over the track names / assignment from quicktime, so if the track is assigned to be Left Surround, this will be carried over into the wav file ffmpeg makes.
Version ffmpeg-1.1.3 works and exports correct stereo wavs, but all the mono tracks it exports it assigns them 'Center'. So ffmpeg versions after that correctly assigns the names, but will not work with Left Total Right Total, this seems to break it, BUT ONLY WHEN EXPORTING to 24 Bit! 16 bit works fine on all versions.

So in conclusion........
ffmpeg will not export 24 bit stereo audio from a quicktime if the track is assigned Left Total Right Total.